# Converting a double[] array into string[] array

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I would like to know what code to use to convert a double[] array into a string[] array

Comment: loop + String.valueOf...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to create a target array of equal size to the original array, and iterate over it, converting element by element.

Example:

```
double[] d = { 2.0, 3.1 };
String[] s = new String[d.length];

for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    s[i] = String.valueOf(d[i]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I said cast, but that wasn't the proper term; I've added an example and edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you have to iterate and convert every item from double to String.

Alternatively it's also possible to avoid an explicit iteration and do the following:

```
// source array
Double[] d_array = new Double[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

// create a string representation like [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
String s = Arrays.toString(d_array);

// cut off the square brackets at the beginning and at the end
s = s.substring(1, s.length - 1);

// split the string with delimiter ", " to produce an array holding strings
String[] s_array = s.split(", ");
```

Comment: This works well for my purposes. I personally need to print all items, but want to avoid manual iteration if possible.